# Loading JSON on document load/ready for DataTables using SammyJS

Tags: ajax, json, datatables, sammy.js

The DataTable does not load when the view is selected and page refreshed, but only after triggering the view from the navigation. How do I get the view to load on page refresh, versus only from being triggered?

```
this.get('#/campaigns/orders', function (context) {
        this.partial('/Orders/');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/orders',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var orders = $('#results').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": '/api/orders',
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "mData": "Name" },
                        { "mData": "Budget" },
                        { "mData": "StartDate" },
                        { "mData": "EndDate" },
                        { "mData": "Status" },
                        { "mData": "Created" },
                        { "mData": "Changed"}
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.get('#/campaigns/orders', function (context) {
    this.partial('/Orders/');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/orders',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          $("document").on(load, function(){  
          var orders = $('#results').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": '/api/orders',
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "Name" },
                    { "mData": "Budget" },
                    { "mData": "StartDate" },
                    { "mData": "EndDate" },
                    { "mData": "Status" },
                    { "mData": "Created" },
                    { "mData": "Changed"}
                ]
            });
          });
        }
    });
  });
```

This is not tested... this is just to get an idea,

also if it don't work try replacing

```
  $("document").on("load", function(){});
```

with

```
   $("document").ready(function(){     });
```